# JoinClause - Invalid statement. Please check aliases, field identifiers, projections and query conditions

Tags: java, join, dynamic, cloud, storage

I'm using Dynamicloud and something is wrong in my code:

**This is my code:**

```
RecordModel contactFormModel = new RecordModel(contactModelId);
RecordModel userFormModel = new RecordModel(userContactModelId);

DynamicProvider<ContactForm> provider = new DynamicProviderImpl<ContactForm>(new RecordCredential(csk, aci));

contactFormModel.setBoundClass(ContactForm.class);
Query<ContactForm> query = provider.createQuery(contactFormModel);
query.setAlias("contact");

query.setProjection("contact.namef, contact.comments");
JoinClause join = Conditions.innerJoin(userFormModel, "user", "contact.id = user.contactid");
query.join(join);

try {
    RecordResults<ContactForm> list = query.add(Conditions.like("contact.namef", "ProBusiness%")).list();
    System.out.println("list = " + list.getFastReturnedSize());

    if (list.getFastReturnedSize() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Contact Name = " + list.getRecords().get(0).getName());
        System.out.println("Contact Comments = " + list.getRecords().get(0).getComments());
    }

} catch (DynamicloudProviderException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**This code throws the following Exception:**

```
org.dynamicloud.exception.DynamicloudProviderException: Invalid statement.  Please check aliases, field identifiers, projections and query conditions.
```

What's wrong?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi**

The problems is the missing "id" in your projection section.  You need to set the id of one model involved in your JoinClause.

Dynamicloud always order the results by Id, in this case the query has ambiguous columns `user.id` and `contact.id"`

**Try to put the following id in your projection (of course depends of your needs):**

```
    query.setProjection("contact.id, contact.namef, contact.comments");
```

**Hope this helps!**